# Who invented the Leibnitz notation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ for the *second* derivative?

Tags: mathematics, notation, calculus

This [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612437/notation-of-the-second-derivation-where-does-the-d-go) made me wonder where the Leibnitz notation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ for the *second* derivative comes from. It does not arise immediately as the obvious generalization of $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Did Leibnitz use it himself? Or was it introduced later?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Leibniz did use this notation for instance in his paper Supplementum geometriae practicae, *Acta Eruditorum*, April 1693, p. 179 ([Google Books link](https://books.google.nl/books?id=jz7vFXu8ODUC&dq=%22ddx%20dy2%22&pg=PA459#v=onepage&q=%22ddx%20dy2%22&f=false)):

[image]

Comment: So this is an answer.  Note that the colon indicates division.

Comment: Is this paper available online anywhere?

Comment: @michael-bächtold Link added.

Comment: ...and note that the overline above the $y$ actually went over the $d$, as can be seen in the google Books link. But it should not go over the 2. That was an alternative notation to parenthesis, so $\overline{dy}^2=(dy)^2$,

Answer (score 8):

The [differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(infinitesimal)) symbold $dx$ is due to Leibniz.

He introduced also "iterated" differentials; see  :

- H.J.M. Bos, [Differentials and Higher-Order Differentials in the Leibnizian Calculus](http://www.tau.ac.il/~corry/teaching/toldot/download/Bos1974.pdf) (1974), page 17:

> Moreover, to introduce higher-order differentials, first-order differentials have to be conceived as variables ranging over an ordered sequence; if only a single $dx$ is considered, $ddx$ does not make sense. The following quotation
>   from Leibniz ["Monitum de characteribus algebraicis", 1710] illustrates this:
>
> > Further, $ddx$ is the element of the element or the *difference of the differences*, for the quantity $dx$ itself is not always constant, but usually increases or decreases continually.

See also [The Early Mathematical Manuscripts of Leibniz](https://books.google.it/books?id=tCmp_c3Q9S8C&printsec=frontcover) (J.M. Child ed., 1920 - also Dover reprint): manuscript of an answer to Bernhard Nieuwentijt, [page 144-on](https://books.google.it/books?id=tCmp_c3Q9S8C&pg=PA158):

> $dx, ddx, dv, ddv, dy, ddy \ldots$

We have to note that Leibniz has $xx$ for $x^2$; see [page 151](https://books.google.it/books?id=tCmp_c3Q9S8C&pg=PA151) :

> Then, since $y-xx : a \ldots$

Comment: So we have found the numerator in the form $ddx$.  Where do we find (for the first time) the denominator?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar - see e.g. page 156 : $ddy/ddx$.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer leaves no doubt that Leibniz was the first to write $d^2y/(dx)^2$ for the second derivative. But since I've [found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz%27s_notation#Leibniz_notation_for_higher_derivatives) [so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Leibniz's_notation_for_antidifferentiation) [many](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25102/why-is-the-2nd-derivative-written-as-frac-mathrm-d2y-mathrm-dx2/25106#25106) [misleading](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612437/notation-of-the-second-derivative-where-does-the-d-go) [justifications](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475016/leibniz-notation-for-high-order-derivatives?noredirect=1&lq=1) for this [notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477507/is-d2y-dx-a-valid-mathematical-notation/477523) [online](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2156821/multiple-derivative-notation), I feel that something additional needs to be said about it.

Most justifications in the links above are along the lines of: "by formal manipulation" or "too obviously" 
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{d}{dx} =\frac{d^2}{dx^2}.
\tag1
$$
But Leibniz, the Bernoullis or Euler would *not* have approved of this without reservation. Not even if the equation was written in the form 
$$
\frac{d \left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)}{dx} = \frac{d dy}{(dx)^2},
\tag2
$$
which is closer to the standard of the time.

To explain let me make a simple analogy first. No one today would claim that the following is correct
$$
\frac{\log \frac{\log y}{\log x}}{\log x} = \frac{\log \log y}{(\log x)^2},
\tag3
$$
and everyone can spot the error.

Analogously, for Leibniz, $d$ was an operator (he might not have called it that way, but he knew it acted on variables just like $\log$) and he knew the quotient rule for $d$. So he might have approved of the following general equation

$$
\frac{d \left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)}{dx} = \frac{d^2y}{(dx)^2} - \frac{dy\cdot d^2x}{(dx)^3}.
\tag4
$$
The reason the second term on the right disappeared, was because an *additional assumption* was often made: it was assumed that the differential of the differential of $x$ is zero (i.e. $d^2x=0$), or put differently: $dx$ was assumed constant.

This can be seen in the 1693 [article](https://books.google.nl/books?id=jz7vFXu8ODUC&dq=%22ddx%20dy2%22&pg=PA459#v=onepage&q=%22ddx%20dy2%22&f=false) of Leibniz quoted by @ViktorBlasjo, a line above $ddx:\overline{dy}^2$, where he writes

> posita $dy$ constante

It can also be found in Eulers *Institutiones Calculi Differentialis* ([1743](https://books.google.ch/books?id=AQEMCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=euler%20foundations%20of%20differential%20calculus&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibxaaYwaTeAhVQ-aQKHZb2Dl4Q6AEIKjAA#v=snippet&q=%22increases%20uniformly%2C%20so%20that%20the%22&f=false)) § 131.

> Now we will proceed under the assumption that $x$ increases uniformly,
>   so that the first differentials $dx, dx^I , dx^{II},\ldots$ are equal to each
>   other, so that the second and higher differentials are equal to zero.
>   We can state this condition by saying that the differential of $x$, that
>   is $dx$, is assumed to be constant. Let $y$ be any function of $x$; ...

And it can be found in Lacroix's *Traité du calcul différentiel et du calcul intégral* ([1797](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k92729z/f131.image)) p.96

> Pour la simplifier nous observons que l'accroissement $dx$ étant regardé invariable, $f'(x)dx$ se change en $f'(x+dx)dx$ ...

Summarizing: for Leibniz, Euler and others the equation
$$
\frac{d \left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)}{dx} = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}
\tag5
$$ 
was only true under the additional assumption that $dx$ is constant.

This leaves a question for me, which hopefully someone else can answer: when and why did mathematicians forget this additional assumption and simply adopt the notation $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ for what should actually be written as $\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2$?

Comment: Agreed, and your calculation (4) is literally in Bézout ([1767](//google.com/books?id=2-pbAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA20), end of §18). To your concluding question, an answer is hard to pinpoint but Lagrange’s differential-free *Fonctions analytiques* (which has (4) as $(y′/x′)′/x′$, [p. 60](//archive.org/details/theoriedesfoncti00lagr/page/60)) must have been influential. This is discussed in Bos ([1974](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=469624), esp. §5 “Euler’s Program to Eliminate Higher Order Differentials”) and Domingues ([2008](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2654307), §§3.1.1 and 3.2.4).

Comment: As to whether $d^2/\,dx^2$ *should actually be written* $(d\,/\,dx)^2$, I think they were equal by the same [convention](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precedence_(mathematics)) used e.g. for Riemannian $\smash{ds^2}$. Bézout spells it out on the previous page: “To denote the square of $dx$, one should naturally write $\smash{(dx)^2}$; but for simplicity one writes
$\smash{dx^2}$, which cannot cause confusion, and be mistaken for the differential of $\smash{x^2}$, which we agreed [§7] to denote thus $\smash{d(x^2)}$.”

Comment: Thanks for those additional pointers @FrancoisZiegler. I'm not sure if I can follow the reasoning in your second comment. Even if we write $\frac{d^2}{(dx)^2}$ for $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$, I don't see how to arrive there from $\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2$ by using conventions for orders of operations. Take the similar example $\left(\frac{\log}{\log{x}} \right)^2$, which I think is different from $\frac{\log^2}{(\log x)^2}$ with all conventions I can think of.

Comment: You’re right. Equality only follows from what Bézout says under the assumption $ddx=0$ (no second term in (4)).

Comment: A small pointer which I should follow up on: Max Stegemann in his popular _Grundrisse der Differential- Integralrechnung_ 4th Edition [1880](https://archive.org/details/grundrissderdif05steggoog/page/n5) still mentions the requirement dx constant.

Answer (score 1):

I think  $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ comes from multiplying $\frac{dy}{dx}$ by $\frac{d}{dx}$. 
In the Notation(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation#Derivitive) multiplication signifies iteration.

(Disclaimer; This is a very rough response. There have not been any other answers yet, I will look for the notation in a textbook.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That is a very reasonable explanation, but the MSE question that I have linked in the OP raises a good point: even assuming that one can multiply differential terms with impunity, it seems that in this notation one 'factor' $d$ is missing from the denominator.

Comment: @Federico Poloni I guess at least physicians view $dx$ as a quantity itself, rather than a product of d*x, the second differential being compared to the square of the small increment.

Comment: The denominator is the square of $dx$.  Since $dx$ is *not* a product, just write it $dx^2$.  No need for $(dx)^2$.

Comment: @VicAche, you mean physicists, not physicians (= medical doctors).

Comment: @KCd true that :) can't edit or flag myself for edition right?

Comment: @VicAche, indeed, edits are no longer possible after a few minutes.

Answer (score -2):

$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ $y$ = $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is too obviously built from $\frac{d}{dx}$$\frac{d}{dx}$ $y$ = $(\frac{d}{dx})^2$ $y$ to deserve any further explanation.

Comment: I don't see how this contributes to answering the historical part of the question. If your claim is that Leibniz thought like this, you would have to back that up. I personally doubt he thought of $d/dx$ as an object in itself.