# Is it the 'd' or 'D' operator?

Tags: mathematicians, notation, calculus

[Philip J. Davis](https://www.brown.edu/academics/applied-mathematics/philip-j-davis)' article on the [history of the gamma function](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Chauvenet/Davis.pdf) (PDF) mentions how [Leibniz](https://www.iep.utm.edu/leib-ove/) proposed the [iterated differential operator](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath616/kmath616.htm) (p. 851 in the upper right corner, or p. 3 of the PDF, about half-way down the page).

Dr. Davis uses a lower-case 'd' in his article.  However, most contemporary literature (er, Web sites), shows an upper-case 'D' for this.  Examples:

- https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath616/kmath616.htm (same link as above)
- http://chalkdustmagazine.com/features/fractional-calculus/
- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html
- https://medium.com/@notaredpanda/fractional-calculus-48192f4e9c9f
- https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ddns/2011/562494/
- http://www.xuru.org/fc/riemannliouville.asp

I'm copy-editing Davis' paper (just for fun and to practice LaTeX), and so now I'm curious:

### What did Leibniz use - 'd' or 'D'?

Please note that I'm asking specifically about the *iterated* differential operator (often called a [Riemann-Liouville fractional derivative](https://www.google.com/search?q=riemann%20liouville%20fractional%20derivative), or RLFD), and not the 'd' in Leibniz's $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}$ notation (although they are related).

Comment: Lower case. See https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/3323/6514, in particular the answer by Mauro Allegranza.

Comment: If by $D$ you mean an operator which acts on things of type $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ (modern functions), then Leibniz had none of that, since he did not have modern functions. He had a small $d$, (the one you explicitly want to exclude), which acted on variable quantities, which modern mathematicians don't know how to make sense of.

Comment: The first hit that I got for your Google search is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Liouville_integral#Fractional_derivatives and here we can see both a decorated $d$ applied to variable quantities and a decorated $D$ applied to modern functions.  And as Michael noted above, Leibniz had only the former.  (Although it seems to me that that bit on Wikipedia might better be rewritten to use only the latter.)